# Find the first index of recurring elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given a numpy array with recurring elements:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1])
```

How can I find the first index of each recurring element (1, 2, 3, 1)? I would like it to return an array of indices:

```
>> index
array([0, 4, 7, 12])
```

Note: The elements in the array can repeat so they are not unique.
Edit: Is there a way that works for an array of strings as well?

```
a = numpy.array(["a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a np.diff with np.where and add the 0th element:

```
np.concatenate(([0],np.where(np.diff(a)!=0)[0]+1))
```

---

```
array([ 0,  4,  7, 12], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can extend this for an array of strings as well?
e.g.: a = numpy.array(["a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"])

Answer (score 0):

`np.searchsorted` is fast if the array is in *ascending* order

```
np.searchsorted(a, [1,2,3,4])
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  4,  7, 14])
```

If the array is not sorted you will need to sort it back and forth with argsort:

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4]) 
i = a.argsort()
i[np.searchsorted(a[i], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5])]
```

Output:

```
array([ 7,  0,  5, 13,  3])
```

This also works:

```
i[np.searchsorted(a, [0, 1, 2, 4, 5], sorter=i)]
```

Output:

```
array([ 7,  0,  5, 13,  3])
```